# error use of enum without previous declaration?

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ from a book and the following example doesn't work in codeblocks. My compiler gives an error:

> use of enum `'Days'` without previous declaration

Can someone enlight me here?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() // main routine
{
    int a;
    enum Days (zo,ma,di,wo,do,vr,za); // <error here> : use of enum 'Days' without previous declaration
    Days today;
    today = ma;
    if (today == zo || today == za)
        cout << "weekend \n"
    else
        cout << "ohno workday \n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Those parentheses should be braces.

Comment: @chris: Care to make that an actual answer? ;)

Comment: @K-ballo, I just quickly noticed that. I didn't really look hard enough to figure out that it fixes it :p

Comment: Just to note, if you don't like your job, get another job. I haven't had that weekend/workday feeling for 15 years.

Comment: @peter wood; what made you conclude that ? do you know me ?

Comment: @user613326 Well, you say "oh no" in relation to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're using `enum` incorrectly. Your parentheses should be braces:

```
enum Days {zo,ma,di,wo,do,vr,za};
```

Now `zo` will be equal to 0, since you didn't explicitly define a value, and each thereafter will be one more than the last.

Also notice (easily, due to syntax highlighting) that `do` conflicts with the `do` keyword reserved for `do...while` statements.

Comment: Thanks !
especially for the do reminder without that i still had errors